# How to have a div ignoring it's parent's display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent `div` with `display: flex`. I would like for one of the child `div` to ignore that.

For example I want something like this:

Child div1

Child div2, Child div3, Child div4

I want the first Child div1 to be on top without having any other elements in it's line. I know I can make this happen if I just take the child div1 outside of it's parent, but it would be nice to know another way.

```
/* Parent div */
.boxContainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Child div1 */
.headerBox {
    height: 100px;
}
 /* more child div */
.imgBox {
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 375px;
    width: 375px;
}
```

Comment: This really is best done by moving the header outside the container. Especially in the case of a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take the item completely outside the flexbox flow, you can set it's position 
to `absolute`, and then move it where you want with `top`, `left`, etc...

Set `position: absolute` on the child, and `position: relative` on the parent:

```
.boxContainer {
  /** Parent div **/
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.headerBox {
  /** Child div1 **/
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  /** move it up **/
  height: 100px;
}

.imgBox {
  /** more child div **/
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 375px;
  width: 375px;
}
```

If you just need the 1st item apart you can use flex wrap, and set `margin-right: 100%` on the 1st element:

```css
/* Parent div */

.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px; /** I've changed the dimensions to fit the demo windows **/
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* Child div1 */

.headerBox {
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}


/* more child div */

.imgBox {
  height: 75px;
  /** I've changed the dimensions to fit the demo windows **/
  width: 75px;
  /** I've changed the dimensions to fit the demo windows **/
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="headerBox">headerBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>

  <div class="imgBox">imgBox</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

> I want the first Child div1 to be on top without having any other
>   elements in it's line.

The simplest way would be to set `flex-basis: 100%` on the 1st child.

With that it will take full width and push the rest items down, and it is fully responsive.

Also, you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
/* Parent div */
.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;               /*  added  */
  align-content: flex-start;     /*  added, so they align at the top  */
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Child div1 */
.headerBox {
  flex-basis: 100%;              /*  added  */
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 2px;
}

/* more child div */
.imgBox {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">

  <div class="headerBox">Header box</div>

  <div class="imgBox">Image box</div>
  <div class="imgBox">Image box</div>
  <div class="imgBox">Image box</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first child element doesn't need to ignore flex. If `flex-basis` is set to 100% it will take up the full width. And then using `flex-wrap: wrap;` for the rest of the child elements to follow on a new line.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent > div:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

/* flex is shorthand for flex-grow + flex-shrink + flex-basis */
```

See demo here: https://codepen.io/eystein/pen/qXmVPo

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning

```css
.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -110px;
  left: 0;
}

.imgBox {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 375px;
  width: 375px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="headerBox"></div>
  <div class="imgBox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you don't really want a `flexbox`. I'd use `float: left` for this. Use `clear: left` on a div that is `width: 0` to get the next ones to wrap to the next line. Flexbox is nice, but if the older tech works better for you then use it.

**Edit:** After looking at the post again I didn't realize you wanted the first div to also take up 100% of the width. This is better done with a flexbox, setting the `flex-basis` as other answers have stated. Going to leave this answer for others to find though.

Example:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
}

.container .img{
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.clear-left{
  clear: left;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="clear-left"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
```